# How to figure out integer boundaries in C

Tags: c

I'm working on a program where I need to know the exact boundaries on signed integers in C. My question is, if you compile a program that depends on this boundary, do you have to check the local environment to see how many bits are used to hold the value?

I'll try to explain this better. Whenever I write a C program that works with signed integers, and part of that program depends on large numbers, I worry about a simple calculation overflowing: say 4,294,967,296 + 1. What will happen? Will this number roll over to a negative number?

Does it depend on how I compile the program (in other words, the compiler I use to compile the program) or does it depend on the environment that my .exe is run on?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

((sizeof(n) + sizeof(int) - 1) & ~(sizeof(int) - 1))

This should give you the limit

Comment: while this is *technically* true, a much more standard way would just be to use the limits file..

Comment: Thanks AurA! But what worries me is where those sizeof() functions are returning their values from. So what you're saying is, it depends on the system the .exe is running on. I have to check this while my program is running, is that what you're saying?

Comment: @dvanaria if you are asking for how sizeof is implemented, then you must [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718896/how-is-the-sizeof-operator-implemented-in-c) previous post.

Comment: @AurA how ((sizeof(n) + sizeof(int) - 1) & ~(sizeof(int) - 1)) diffrent from sizeof(int)

Comment: sizeof(int) will give 2 or 4 bytes depending on your compiler... but here the question asked is the range of int values can go upto

Answer (score 2):

It depends only on how you compiled your program, i.e. you don't need to check "the environment" at run-time. For anything that matters you should use fixed size integer types from `<stdint.h>`, e.g. `int32_t`.

You can check the ranges of integer types using constants from `<limits.h>`, e.g. `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Thanks. Is that ANSI C or what version does that fall under? I'm not familiar with <stdint.h>. That's the ISO C standard? How do I know if my compiler adheres to that?

Comment: This is the current C standard, C99.

Comment: @PaulR: arriving Dec. 8, 2011, the programming world received another pile of stone tables from the Gods above, named C11!

Comment: @slartibartfast: yes - C11 is still a little too new to be considered "current" I think - so far only gcc 4.6 among the mainstream compilers seems to have C11 support.

Answer (score 2):

The header `#include <limits.h>` includes the constants you need, including:

- `CHAR_BIT` - the number of bits in a `char`.
- `CHAR_MAX` - the maximum value for a plain `char`.
- `SCHAR_MAX` - the maximum value for a `signed char`.
- `UCHAR_MAX` - the maximum value for an `unsigned char`.
- `SHRT_MAX` - the maximum value for a `short`.
- `USHRT_MAX` - the maximum value for an `unsigned short`.
- `INT_MAX`
- `UINT_MAX`
- `LONG_MAX`
- `ULONG_MAX`
- `LLONG_MAX`
- `ULLONG_MAX`

For the signed types, there are also minima:

- `CHAR_MIN` - plain `char`; the value might be 0 or a negative number.
- `SCHAR_MIN`
- `SHRT_MIN`
- `INT_MIN`
- `LONG_MIN`
- `LLONG_MIN`

The behaviour of unsigned arithmetic on overflow is completely defined (the value produced is correct modulus `UINT_MAX + 1` or similar, depending on the types of the operands).

The behaviour of signed arithmetic on overflow is undefined and is far better avoided than investigated.  Any given compiler may handle it any way it chooses.  Traditionally, the values on overflow often wrapped (adding two big positive but signed integers often produced a negative value).  However, modern C compilers are less forgiving.

The integer constants above can be used to help prevent overflow if you are really worried about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `limits.h` header. It defines constants for maximum and minimum values of the different types.

Comment: Ok right. That's what I initially thought. So that depends on my dev environment right? That depends on the limits.h file my compiler reads during compilation, is that what you're saying?

Comment: Correct. It contains preprocessor macros, which are evaluated at compile time to give you the actual value depending on your environment.

Comment: OK great insight, thanks. It doesn't matter if my executable is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine?

Comment: That's the whole point - to make your source code independent of the architecture it's compiled on/for.

Answer (score 1):

> say 4,294,967,296 + 1. What will happen? Will this number roll over to a negative number?

That number, if unsigned, will rollover to 0 if you add to it. An unsigned int would rollover to the lowest negative number if you add 1 to the highest positive number.

Comment: Right but how do I know if that number will rollover? It doesn't matter about that exact value I used in my example, it could be any value that I'm trying to modify. How do I know it won't cause roll-over? Thanks for your input btw.

Comment: Quite unlikely. 4,294,967,296 plus 1 will give 4,294,967,297 because 4,294,967,296 is an object with more than 32 significant bits OR it is a compile time error (in case the compiler can't handle anything > 32 bits). Now, 4,294,967,295 + 1 (which you likely meant) will roll over to 0 in a C program that translates the constant to a 32 bit unsigned entity.

Comment: Behaviour on signed overflow is undefined.