# Implementing custom sizeof operator

Tags: c++, sizeof

I am working on a class that is used to create integers with custom sizes, like 3, 5, 6, 7 bytes and in need of a custom sizeof operator which would invoke the SizeOf function when it gets a csnumeric type else uses the inbuilt sizeof operator.

It works perfectly if i use the sizeof_x_is_type macro on a typename or if i use the sizeof_x_is_variable on a variable, my problem is that i cant seem to make a macro that could handle both typenames and variables and call the appropriate functions.

I cant seem to find a way to distinguish between a typename or variable.
The closest i came up with is is_variable() function which can distinguish between a typename or an integer using template parameters.

Is there any way to call different functions depending on whether we get a typename or a variable?

Edit:

I need the custom sizeof so i can use my custom integer type with a class which uses sizeof to read and write into a buffer

```
template<typename T, uint8 Size, T Mask>
class csnumeric : public csnumeric_base
{
    private:

       static uint8 constexpr m_Size = Size; 

    public:

       static constexpr uint8 SizeOf() noexcept { return m_Size; }

    rest of code goes here...
}

using int56 = csnumeric<int64, 7, 0x00FFFFFFFFFFFFFF>;
using int48 = csnumeric<int64, 6, 0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF>;
using int40 = csnumeric<int64, 5, 0x000000FFFFFFFFFF>;
using int24 = csnumeric<int32, 3, 0x00FFFFFF>;
using uint56 = csnumeric<uint64, 7, 0x00FFFFFFFFFFFFFF>;
using uint48 = csnumeric<uint64, 6, 0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF>;
using uint40 = csnumeric<uint64, 5, 0x000000FFFFFFFFFF>;
using uint24 = csnumeric<uint32, 3, 0x00FFFFFF>;

template<typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<csnumeric_base, T>::value, std::size_t>::type csnumeric_sizeof() noexcept { return T::SizeOf(); }

template<typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<csnumeric_base, T>::value, std::size_t>::type csnumeric_sizeof() noexcept { return sizeof(T); }

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_variable() noexcept { return false; }

template<uint32 T>
constexpr bool is_variable() noexcept { return true; }

#define sizeof_x_is_type(x) csnumeric_sizeof<x>()
#define sizeof_x_is_variable(x) csnumeric_sizeof<decltype(x)>()
#define sizeof_custom(x) ( is_variable<x>() ? sizeof_x_is_variable(x) : sizeof_x_is_type(x) )
```

Comment: Recommend giving [How is the sizeof operator implemented in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718896/how-is-the-sizeof-operator-implemented-in-c) a read. This may have changed, but I can't imagine why anyone would want it to.

Comment: What happens if someone tries to use `sizeof` to allocate storage for your class?

Comment: "with a class which uses sizeof to read and write into a buffer" This is a dangerous class if misused. How would it handle a string, for example?

Comment: It will return the size of the underlying type, so for example sizeof(uint24) will return 4 as its underlying type is unsigned int, and i want it to return 3 hence the need of custom sizeof

Comment: the buffer class has special cases for things like std::string

Comment: Isn't it easier to also add a special case for csnumeric?

Comment: You're missing part of what we are trying to say here. `sizeof` is a really low-level utility that is used to allocate storage, advance pointers, and other stuff that will totally expletive deleted up if you lie to it. Say you have allocated 32 bits to hold your 24 bit int. Now say you have an array of them. Where does `arr[2]` go in memory to get the value? If you want a 24 bit data type that really is 24 bits because you have to use `sizeof`, make it a wrapper around an array of three bytes.

Comment: yes it is easier, i have already done that, but wanted to see if something like custom sizeof is possible for it, i feel like it is a hackfix because one has to know the type uses ::SizeOf instead of sizeof and it would like the class to behave like a primitive

Comment: No. Trying to hack `sizeof` is a hackfix.

Comment: Sadly having an array of 3 bytes will still result in sizeof 4 because of padding in the class, that was the first implemention i tried

Comment: Yuck. You've got me there. I've spent too long in itty-bitty space where you can do this stuff. You can look into packed structures and the like, but they don't port well. See where you are going and it's a cool idea to simplify your case, but it would over complicate pretty much every other case. This is a good question with an answer of no, I'm afraid.

Comment: Damn. So there is no way to detect whether something is a type or a variable at compilation time?

Comment: I think there is a proposal to reduce `template <typename T, T value>` to somehing like `template <auto value>`. then you could do your distinction (with constexpr value).